# How we can click on signup button on spicejet official site by mousehover action with selenum

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can we click on the signup button on the SpiceJet official website with Selenium Mousehour actions?

> [image]

Comment: Why you want to hover n click ? Can you try to direct click on that button

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.